# Python Universal Robots UR-RTDE's API - Getting sporadic "RTDEReceiveInterface Exception: End of file"

Tags: python, api, exception, robotics

Been using happily [ur-rtde](https://pypi.org/project/ur-rtde/) and lately started getting "RTDEReceiveInterface Exception: End of file" messages in different places of the code.

It seems it happens only when the robot is at rest.

Anyone sees this?